# IN clause in pig

Tags: apache-pig

```
user1,action,aa
user2,comedy,cc
user3,drama,dd
user4,action,aa
user5,action,aa
user6,comedy,cc
user7,action,aa
user8,comedy,cc
user9,drama,dd
user10,action,aa
user11,action,aa
user12,comedy,cc
```

i want to replace all 'aa' with 'bb' if corresponding role are from (action,comedy) . Couldnt find case statement support or other approaches for the same!

Comment: Is this an SQL Question? What are you trying to achieve and what have you attempted??

Comment: hi @KebabProgrammer this isnt a SQL question... data alteration needs to be done on a huge dataset hence the question.

i have attempted to use `CASE` statement then realized it wont support `IN`

Comment: Yea, Elaborate on it then, you need to add more than what you have right now if you want a good response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is loaded to the relation A, then use case statement to check the value of $1 i.e. second field in the relation A and when it is 'action' OR 'comedy' replace the value 'aa' with 'bb' or else use the default value $2

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0,$1,
               (CASE $1
                    WHEN 'action' OR 'comedy' THEN REPLACE($2,'aa','bb')
                    ELSE $2 END);
```